# Proving Chords to be Equal using Radical Axis

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

a) Prove that the midpoints of the four common tangents to two nonintersecting circles lie on one line.

b) Through two of the tangent points of common exterior tangents with two circles a line is drawn. Prove that the circles cut on this line equal chords.

[image]

Comment: okay thank you @lesath82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part a): Depending on how you define the radical axis (say of two non intersecting circles), one of the most standard definition is that it is the locus of all points on the plane with the property that if you draw the tangents form the point to the two circles (there are a total of four tangents, two for each circle), they are equal. Then one shows this locus is a line. Consequently, the midpoints mentioned in your problem have exactly that property. So therefore they all lie on the radical axis of the two circles, which is a line.

Part b): Follows directly from the secant-tangent theorem (or whatever it is called). Denote by $T_A, \, T_B$ the points of tangency of the upper common external tangent so that $T_A$ is closet to $A$ while $T_B$ is closest to $B$, $\, T_D$,   and denote by $T_D, \, T_E$ the points of tangency of the lower common external tangent so that $T_D$ is closet to $D$ while $T_E$ is closest to $E$. Take segment $T_AT_E$ and let it intersect the left circle at point $K$ and the right one at point $L$. You are asked to show that $KT_A = LT_E$ right? Indeed looking at the right circle and it's tangent $T_AT_B$ together with its secant $T_AT_E$ with intersection point $L$
$$T_AT_E \cdot T_AL = (T_AT_B)^2$$ Analogously, looking at the left circle and it's tangent $T_ET_D$ together with its secant $T_ET_A = T_AT_E$ with intersection point $K$
$$T_AT_E \cdot T_EK = (T_ET_D)^2$$ However, $T_AT_B=T_ET_D$ so 
$$T_AT_E \cdot T_AL = T_AT_E \cdot T_EK$$ which after canceling out $T_AT_E$ leaves us with $T_EK = T_AL$. Therefore
$$KT_A = T_AT_E - T_EK = T_AT_E - T_AL = LT_E$$
$$$$

Answer (score 0):

Your title invokes Radical Axis, so I shall suppose that existence and properties of such a *locus* can be safely used (in case, have a look [here](http://mathgardenblog.blogspot.it/2013/07/radical-axis.html)). Moreover the title suggest that they *should* be. With this in mind, I have a solution for point a, non for point b.

When you say "we can clearly see that etc"... in fact your deduction is so uncertain that it is actually wrong! Point P is not collinear with N and M! You were deceived by your figure, but every statement should be proved, it is never enough "clear"! Moreover, even if P, N and M were on the same line as they seem, this wouldn't necessarily be the Radical Axis until you prove it!

If you look at my figures, the error becomes apparent: two other points, other than P, are the ones that lie on the same line as N and M. And indeed we'll prove that all these points are collinear exactly by showing that they all belong to the Radical Axis.

This turns out to be straightforward, by the same definition of this *locus*. When for exampe N is defined as the middle point of the upper tangent, it's easy to show (by transitive property combined with the properties of the tangents to a circle conducted by the same point) that all four needed segments are equal. Look at the blue subset of my figure. The same holds true for the light blue lower tangent. Now look at the brown and green tangents: there is nothing that guarantees that they cut each other in halves, and in fact this is not the case. So their midpoints are distinct, and for each of them one shall repeat the same considerations done for N and M. And we are done!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: so to prove (a) we just have to use power of a point? would you be able to help me do that? @lesath82

Comment: As Futorogist says, if you look at the easiest definition of Radical Axis, for example on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis, you'll see that it's not necessary to have knowledge of the power of a point to prove point a. As for point b, I too have a demonstration (honestly much uglier than Futorologist's, so that mine is now useless) but looking at the title I suspect that there is a way that exploits the Radical axis. The same tan-sec theorem is part of the wider topic of power of points. I'm afraid that findind such a solution is out of my reach. I'm updating my answer accordingly.